# Dynamic loading bundle at runtime MVC5 razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, bundle

I want some js in bundle just loaded if the login user is admin.
Something like this:

```
@if (@ViewBag.IsAdmin)
{
    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/admin")
    }
}
```

if he's administrator, i hope the section "Scripts" will be filled. However, on client side, i cannot see the js in "~/bundles/admin" package.

I have changed my code and not using @section:

```
@if (@ViewBag.IsAdmin)
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/admin")
}
```

But the same issue. It looks like the bundle cannot be loaded dynamically at runtime.

The only way i can pass it:

```
@if (@ViewBag.IsAdmin)
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/admin.js"></script>
}
```

That means load js directly instead of putting it in bundle.
So my question: Is there anyway i can load a bundle dynamically ?

Comment: Show how do you define the bundle. Does the bundle script get loaded without the `if` condition?

Comment: It loaded without the if condition, i will update my bundle define later in the question for clearer meaning.

Comment: Are you sure then that the `ViewBag.IsAdmin` is actually true? Try debuggig this code.

Comment: I debug the code and sure it pass the line to generate the bundle. I'm not sure why but i just try restarting visual studio and it's ok now @.@ sorry for my dump question @.@

Answer (score 0):

I do this and it works for me:

```
@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/bundles/dataTablesStyles")
    @if (Model.isReportAdmin){@Styles.Render("~/bundles/X-editablecss")}
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/highcharts")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dataTablesScripts")
    @if (Model.isReportAdmin){@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/X-editablejs")}
}
```